# on submit form, couldn't get react-select values

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-select

```
onSubmit(values) {
   console.log("i m clicked", values);  /// i didn't get form values 
    here. 
}

renderMacros() {
const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
const macrosData = this.props.macros.macros;
const categoryMacrosData = this.props.categoryMacros.category;
console.log("categoryMacrosData", categoryMacrosData);
const { open } = this.state;
if (macrosData) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="form-block-5 w-form">
        <form
          id="macros-form"
          name="macros-form"
          onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}
        >
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-sm-12">
              <label>Type</label>
              <Field   // this works fine
                name="category"
                options={MACRO_TYPE_CATEGORIES}
                placeholder="Type"
                component={SelectInput}
                set_default="true"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-12">
              <Field     // this works fine
                name="name"
                placeholder="Name Ex. Follow-up template"
                component={renderField}
                type="text"
                className="text-fields w-input"
                id="macros_name"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-12">
              <Field    // here is the problem
                type="text"
                name="categoryId"
                options={categoryMacrosData}
                placeholder="Search or add category "
                component={AsyncMulti}
                handleSelect={this.handleSelectChange}
              />
            </div>                
          </div>
          <button>Create Macro</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

}

> Bottom line is if i use Creatable component of react-select library, i
>   couldn't get selected values.

My component file:  `components/Multi.js`

```
 import React from "react";
 import CreatableSelect from "react-select/lib/Creatable";

 const MultiSelect = props => {
 const { options, handleSelect } = props;
 return <CreatableSelect isMulti onChange={handleSelect} options= 
  {options} />;
 };

 export default MultiSelect;
```

> I am using react-select for select options in redux form. After
>   submitting form, I am unable to get form submitted values.
>   I am using react-select library https://react-select.com/creatable with redux form.

Answer (score 1):

Given a props name in `<Select>` like

```
<Select
    name = {"inputName"} // <- if you submit the form you will get vale like {"inputName":test111}
    options = {[{ value: 'test111', label: 'Chocolate' }]}
/>
```

Answer (score -1):

You are not binding `handleSubmit` properly as well not using `refs` since you are not getting the values.

I suggest you to try with the binding code in your `<form>` tag:

```
<form
  id="macros-form"
  name="macros-form"
  onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}
>
```

Also pass `refs` in your field tag to get the value:

```
<Field
  name="categoryId"
  options={categoryMacrosData}
  placeholder="Search or add category "
  component={Multi}
  handleSelect={this.handleSelectChange}
  ref="categoryId"                      
 />
```

Instead of writing `onSubmit` function:

```
onSubmit(values) {
   console.log("i m clicked", values);  /// i didn't get form values 
    here. 
}
```

Replace it with this function code:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
   if (this.refs.categoryId !== '') {
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log('categoryId: ', this.refs.categoryId.value)
    }
}
```

Hope it helps you!